# Grant privilege to role with admin option Vs Grant role to user with admin option?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-security

I am little confused between following two CASES, though I know the result but I am not very convinced with the reason behind it. Need help from database experts.

(Say) A role ROLE1 is created along with USER1 and USER2 by dba

`connect /as sysdba
create user USER1 identified by xyz;
create user USER2 identified by abc;
create role ROLE1;`

**CASE 1:**

1. A ‘select any table’ privilege is granted to ROLE1 without admin option

   `connect /as sysdba
   grant select any table to ROLE1;`
2. Grant ROLE1 to USER1 with admin option

   `connect /as sysdba
   grant ROLE1 to USER1 with admin option;`
3. Can USER1 now grant 'select any privilege' to other users?

   `connect USER1/xyz
   grant select any table to USER2;`

I got ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error here, which means it is not the right way.

**CASE 2:**

1. A ‘select any table’ privilege is granted to ROLE1 with admin option

   `connect /as sysdba
   grant select any table to ROLE1 with admin option;`
2. Grant ROLE1 to USER1 irrespective of whether you grant it w/ or w/o admin option

   `connect /as sysdba
   grant ROLE1 to USER1;`
3. Can USER1 now grant 'select any privilege' to other users?

   `connect USER1/xyz
   grant select any table to USER2;`

This works perfectly without reporting any error.

Can any one please help understand why CASE2 works and why not CASE1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CASE1:**

`grant ROLE1 to USER1 with admin option;` means you can grant `ROLE1` to other users, regardless what have been granted to `ROLE1`. Thus `grant select any table to USER2;` does not work.

However, `grant ROLE1 to USER2;` should work.

**CASE2:**

You get permission (through role `ROLE1`, like `DBA` role gets it) to grant `select any table` to other users. So, `grant select any table to USER2;` works.

On the other hand `grant ROLE1 to USER2;` should fail.